# How to use nltk in android using Kivy and buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, nltk, buildozer

I need to test NLTK program in android with Kivy. But app crashes when I open the app. Program has no errors. I tried modifying the buildozer.spec file(added nltk in kivy requirements) but it didn't workout. How to make it work?

Here is the "app" section of buildozer.spec file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = NLTK APP

# (str) Package name
package.name = nltkapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy, android, nltk

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was so long for you I doubt you care anymore but I'm encountering the same issue and here is how far I've gotten...

You need to add more dependencies to your

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = python2,kivy,goslate,chardet,idna,nltk
```

I think if you add those your App will at least start... but honestly the best thing I've found from others that has helped me debug is using 'adb logcat' command in your terminal.

1. Goto your phones developer mode and make sure it's 'USB debugging connected' is turned on.
2. Plug your phone into your computer and in a CMD line type: adb logcat
3. Lot's of stuff is going to pop up, wait a little till it settles. This is more or less spitting out everything your phone is doing.
4. Try running your App and check out the error msg it gives you. That is the most valuable debugging you'll get since typically App crashes don't display any error msg.