# NLTK not working in Android Buildozer App with KivyMD

Tags: python, android, nltk, kivymd, buildozer

I am making a basic app with KivyMD, which uses NLTK.
The program works well in Pycharm IDE, but while compiling with Buildozer, the Android App crashes after opening up.
JSON works well importing the json file dataset; so, I suppose..NLTK has some issues.
This is the **main.py** file:

```
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import nltk
import json
with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
words = str(nltk.word_tokenize(str([data["intents"][0]["patterns"][0]])))
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
stemmertest = stemmer.stem('addition')

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        label = MDLabel(text=words, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.3})
        label2 = MDLabel(text=stemmertest, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.5})
        screen.add_widget(label)
        screen.add_widget(label2)
        return screen
MainApp().run()
```

I am writing the *requirements* in the *Buildozer.spec* as:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1,nltk==3.2.5,goslate,chardet,idna
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

> Goto your phone's developer mode and make sure its 'USB debugging connected' is turned on.
> Plug your phone into your computer and in a CMD line type: ADB logcat
> Lots of stuff is going to pop up, wait for a little till it settles. This is more or less spitting out everything your phone is doing.
> Try running your app and check out the error msg it gives you. That is the most valuable debugging you'll get since typically App crashes don't display any error msg.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825374/9486392

And please share that error message in the question by editing it.

Comment: Whenever I type adb logcat, it gives me an error message...so I am unable to do that...

Comment: So, please answer me directly what should I do please ?